# Post/response to slack in CircleCI

Tags: slack, circleci

As part of my CircleCI pipeline, I would like to start the pipeline by running a command on slack - in this case `/yoink deploy` (we are using Yoink to manage shared resources, and trying to come up with a low-effort way to make sure people aren't stepping on each others toes during deployments). If the response back from the yoink bot is affirmative, continue along the build pipeline. Otherwise, stop it.

The challenge that I'm having is that the Slack integrations for circle let me post a message under different circumstances, but I can't figure out a way to make it use a *reply* from that posted message to choose next pipeline steps. My question is this:

Has anyone previously managed to do something like this with a slack integration with Circle, or is there some other CircleCI method that folks have used to lock and release said lock on deployments?

Comment: I don't know how your integration works, but CircleCI only gives us an API, they don't have an integration that we can interact like that.. however, you can set up this on your side, before doing the deployment, you can query the API to see if there is an active pipeline, and only trigger the API if the pipeline is free. I mean, I have an integration that does that, but I had to write the whole logic, I don't know if you have access to that, if so,  the method  `https://circleci.com/api/v2/pipeline/{pipeline-id}/workflow` would help you.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand. Are you saying that you did that as part of your tooling that triggered your integration, or as part of your circle pipeline config itself?